# How to add custom filter to Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Active Admin allows me to [define filters](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html) that are displayed on the index page like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Promo do

  filter :name
  filter :address
  filter :city
  filter :state
  filter :zip

end
```

I would like to combine all the fields above into one, so that I can search for Promos that contain the search string in name or full address. My model already has a named scope that I can use:

```
class Promo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_name_or_full_address, lambda { |q| where('name LIKE :q OR address LIKE :q OR city LIKE :q OR state LIKE :q OR zip LIKE :q', :q => "%#{q}%") }
end
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Active Admin uses the [meta_search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) gem for its filters. ORed conditions syntax allows to combine several fields in one query, for example

```
Promo.metasearch(:name_or_address_contains => 'brooklyn')
```

In Active Admin DSL this translates to

```
ActiveAdmin.register Promo do

  filter :name_or_address, :as => :string

end
```

Comment: Although it uses Ransack it seems to still support this kind of filter. In my testing, you need to explicitly state `as: :string`.

You can also pass `label: "Custom Label"` if you want a different label.

Answer (score 31):

Active admin uses metasearch. For example you can do this:

```
filter :"subscription_billing_plan_name" , :as => :select, :collection => BillingPlan.all.map(&:name)
```

Comment: note that you probably want your collection to be re-evaluated every time the page loads by putting in a lambda: `collection: lambda { BillingPlan.all.map(&:name) }`. Otherwise if you add a BillingPlan after your app boots, it won't be in the selection.

Comment: getting a wrong number of arguments error (1 for 0) if i use a lambda statement, idea why? Using rails 3.2.17 with active_admin 0.6

Comment: Nice for model enum fields

Comment: use .pluck(:name) instead .map to avoid bringing unnecessary data from the database.

Answer (score 18):

Another way of doing such filtering in newer version of active admin:

```
# app/admin/my_model.rb
filter :my_custom_filter,
as: :numeric,
label: 'Custom Filter',
filters: [:eq]
```

Then add following 2 functions in your model file

Your filtering logic:

```
def self.my_custom_filter_eq(value)
  where(column_1: value) # or probably a more complex query that uses the value inputted by the admin user
end
```

Registering new filter for Ransack

```
def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
  %i(my_custom_filter_eq)
end
```

Comment: In my case I also had to add `my_custom_filter` to the model's `def self.ransackable_attributes` method

Answer (score 13):

To use a custom filter, you can create a scope function and add it as search_methods in the model.

For example, on my User model:

```
search_methods :role_eq
scope :role_eq, -> (role) { where("? LIKE ANY(roles)", role) }
```

Then in users.rb, I can use my scope as a custom filter:

```
filter :role, label: "Roles", as: :select, collection: %w[ student teacher parent ]
```

Comment: Throws `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)`

Comment: Ransack uses `ransackers` instead of `search_methods` for customization

Answer (score 8):

Answering in 2018. ActiveAdmin uses Ransack.

On model itself you need to add Ransack formatter:

```
ransacker :my_custom_filter, formatter: -> (category_id) {
    ids = MyModel.where(category_id: category_id).pluck(:id) # return only id-s of returned items.
    ids.present? ? ids : nil # return ids OR nil!
} do |parent| # not sure why this is needed .. but it is :)
    parent.table[:id]
end
```

In ActiveAdmin file you need to specify the rule:

```
filter :my_custom_filter_in, as: :select, collection: -> { Category.all } # sometimes my_custom_filter_eq - depending on what you want .. Specify different "as" when you need it.
```

Comment: hey I tried this, It's working for & we need parent because it's the column in the table that we'll be searching.

Comment: And I am getting ids as array how to query this for all the array values from ids. Please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

I found better way of doing that. You just need to add:

```
config.clear_sidebar_sections!

sidebar :filters do
  render partial: 'search'
end
```

And then make form inside the `_search` partial with the builder `ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder` as it did in:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/filters/forms.rb

For more information how to do it, look to this gist:

https://gist.github.com/4240801

Another idea is to create class:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Inputs
    class FilterCustomStringInput < FilterStringInput
      def input_name
        "#{super}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

that will be able to invoke by `as: :custom_string`, but I don't like that idea, because you can find soon, that you will need to create custom_select and so on...

Answer (score 2):

I have model **WithdrawalRequest** which belongs to **User** model.

For filtering withdrawal requests by user's email need write:

```
filter :user_id, :as => :select, :collection => User.all.map {|user| [user.email, user.id]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

In my model

```
  scope :active, -> { where(inactive_at: nil) }
  scope :inactive, -> { where.not(inactive_at: nil) }

  ...

  ransacker :listing_status, formatter: proc{ |status|
    ids = status == 'Active' ? active.ids : inactive.ids
    ids = ids.present? ? ids : nil
  }, splat_params: true do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
  end
```

In my admin file

`filter :listing_status_in, as: :select, collection: %w(Active Inactive), label: 'Listing Status'`