# Setting up a has_many through filter with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, meta-search

I'm trying to simply allow filtering of categories on the Locations page for ActiveAdmin.

I have three models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories_locations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categories_locations

class CategoriesLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :location
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categories_locations
    has_many :locations, :through => :categories_locations
end
```

On my locations page, I'm using this filter:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Location do
  filter :name
  filter :category, :collection => proc { Category.all }, :as => :select
```

However, it keeps throwing an error.

```
undefined method `category_eq' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Location:0x007fd4f9b965d8>
```

I've tried filter :categories, filter :categories_locations, but nothing will work.

Has anyone experienced this –– anyone have a solution?

Comment: Am having the same issue, and I can not move from habtm to has_many/through, so any real solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at some point has_many/through is more flexible than habtm (you can have additional fields etc)

Answer (score 4):

I was also searching for same and found working solution as below. Posting here so it may help others in future.

**app/admin/location.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Location do
  filter :filter_by_category, label: 'Category', as: :select, collection: Category.pluck(:name, :id)
```

**app/model/location.rb**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories_locations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categories_locations

  def self.filter_by_category(category_id)
    category_id = 1 if category_id == true # this is required only for id=1, ActiveAdmin return it as `true`
    joins(:categories).where("categories.id = ?", category_id)
  end

  #  Add your custom method as ransack 
  def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
    [:filter_by_category]
  end
end
```

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this can be found here providing you can write your has many though in sql!

[How to add custom filter to Active Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983654/how-to-add-custom-filter-to-active-admin)

Answer (score -1):

why aren't you using habtm?

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

class CategoriesLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end
```

and then

```
ActiveAdmin.register Location do
  filter :name
  filter :category_id, :collection => proc { Category.all }, :as => :select
```