# Changing ActiveAdmin resources dynamically in a dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have to make and ActiveAdmin page, in which the top section I should put a drop down menu. In the drop down menu the user can change the resource, from where Active Admin loads the page. Each resource represents an Oracle View.
How can that be developed?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the filters provided by ActiveAdmin to get the same result. With a custom filter, as described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983654/how-to-add-custom-filter-to-active-admin), you can do basically anything to the collection that is displayed on an index page.