# Trying to implement 'contains' filter on ActiveAdmin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Some had posted similar question as mine. I tried the solution to most of them. Some say ActiveAdmin is using Metasearch and some say it's using ransack. I tried both methods. 
My activeadmin version is  1.0.0.pre4 and rails 4.2.6
Follwing is my code for the user based filter:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Equipment do
    filter :user
end
```

This gives me a `user` dropdown where I can select one of the user and it filters the result based on that user. Right now I have only 3 users so its fine. But in future it will grow to thousands. So instead I would like to have a `contains` field, where I can enter user name and filter.
I tried changing to following:

```
filter :user, as: :string, label: 'User'
```

and also

filter :items_user, as: :string

Didn't work. Can somebody please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
filter :user_name, as: :string
```

where `name` is attribute of User Model.

Comment: For some reason, `as: :string` does not work well on associations. On my case, it raises a `NoMethodError, undefined method 'user_name_contains' for Ransack::Search class: User, base: Grouping  combinator: and Ransack::Search`

Comment: how to filter for user's first name & last name

Comment: @pavankumarv you need to setup custom filter please refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/7983654/6270554